# Installing python package "youtube2zim": "The libzim library cannot be found."

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, youtube, virtualenv

### Specs

- M2 MacBook Air
- MacOS Ventura 13.4.1 (c)
- Python and "virtualenv" installed via HomeBrew (python@3.11)
- using zsh shell

### Objective

I want to install the following python package ("youtube2zim"):

https://pypi.org/project/youtube2zim/

### Steps to reproduce

I'm following the installation instructions under the "Virtualenv" header of the same webpage, which I've pasted here:

```
virtualenv -p python3 ./ # Create virtualenv
source bin/activate      # Activate the virtualenv
pip3 install youtube2zim # Install dependencies
youtube2zim --help       # Display youtube2zim help
```

### Error

After

```
pip3 install youtube2zim
```

, the installation stops here:

```
Collecting libzim<1.2,>=1.1.0 (from zimscraperlib<1.9,>=1.8.0->youtube2zim)
  Using cached libzim-1.1.0.tar.gz (8.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [2 lines of output]
      [!] The libzim library cannot be found.
      Please verify it is correctly installed and can be found.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

### Any ideas?

Thanks for taking the time to read this :)

Comment: It is pulling an old version of libzim. That old version doesn't support ARM (Mac M1). You need a newer version of libzim for that.

Comment: Try installing libzim manually, from https://download.openzim.org/release/libzim/?

Comment: @bobtho'-' Tried downloading the latest version for macOS Arm ("libzim_macos-arm64-8.2.1.tar.gz                    20-Jul-2023 14:27     20M"), then ran "python3 -m pip install ./Downloads/libzim_macos-arm64-8.2.1.tar.gz", according to instructions from here: "https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/?highlight=tar.gz#installing-from-local-archives", but got the following error for some reason, is there some other way I'm meant to install it? > "file:/// [etc.] does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found."

Comment: Libzim isn't a Python package; it's a program you install on your system. Try following the instructions on the libzim website to install it (you probably should extract it to someplace in your path).